# Retrieving cookies from httprequest in Xamarin.forms

Tags: web-services, cookies, xamarin.forms, session-cookies

help me, i couldn't get the cookies from an httprequest, i tried the plugins.settings, i tried the pcl share too, am in this problem for a month

```
        public async Task<bool> PostAsync(AuthUser user)
    {
        var CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = 
        CookieContainer };
        var _client = new HttpClient(handler);

        IEnumerable<string> cookieStrings = null;
        //var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
         MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            try
            {
                string url = WebServiceUrl + "j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + user.j_username +"&j_password=" + user.j_password + "&ajax=true";
            HttpResponseMessage result = await _client.PostAsync(url, httpContent);

                IEnumerable<string> cookies;
                if (result.Headers.TryGetValues("set-cookie", out cookies))
                {
                    foreach (var c in cookies)
                    {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Cookie", c , "OK");
                    }
                }
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using (var responsecontent = result.Content)
                    {
                    string resultString = responsecontent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthUser>(resultString);
                        if (response.error != null)
                        {
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", response.result.error, "OK");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if (response.result.success.Equals("1"))
                        {
                        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TimelineMenuPage(response.result.user_id.ToString(), response.result.token));

                        return true;
                        }

                    }
                }
                return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
               await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", e.ToString(), "OK");
              throw;
            }
        }
```

when debugging it skips this part :

```
if (result.Headers.TryGetValues("set-cookie", out cookies))
{
foreach (var c in cookies)
{
await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Cookie", c , "OK");
}
}
```

**and then i get in CookieContainer count=0 **

Comment: First of all to avoid the question being closed. Please post the full question here on StackOverflow, without linking to another website. Avoid saying thanks, or please help me in your question as well. We know you need help, we assume you will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using a CookieContainer, and you will know the Uri you are getting them from, why don't you just get the Cookies directly from the Container, instead of a set-cookie command, that you will then have to parse.

```
cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("mydomain.com"));
```

After your HttpRequest, it will automatically put them into the CookieContainer.

Comment: am not using set cookie, i am using this:
IEnumerable<Cookie>responsecookies = CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
foreach(Cookie c in responsecookies){
CookieContainer.Add(uri,new Cookie());}

Comment: i found some where while searshing is that there is an attribure (HttpOnly) from false to true, is it possible with xamarin?

Comment: same result with set or no, always count=0

Comment: @Refka - do your headers even contain a set-cookie value? If you loop through all headers you receive, what are you seeing? If there is no set-cookie, they are no cookies.

Comment: hello @Adam Pedley, i found it when inspecting in navigator, the cookie is hidden in the header of the request so i did this : 
   request.AddHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+token);
and it worked

Comment: Glad you found it, however, just to clarify, the Cookie wasn't hidden in your request, just the information you were after. The server wasn't sending a cookie.